# c++ pointer assignment confusion

Tags: c++11, pointers

Consider this MCV example

```
class A
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        B();
       ~B();
    };
public:
    B* a, b, c;
    A();
    ~A();
    void foo();
};

A::foo()
{
    a = b = c;
}
```

yields the following compilation error in Visual Studio 2015

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'A::B *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Strangely if I declare a, b, and c as follows

```
B* a; B* b, B* c;
```

There is no compilation issue. Because the pointers are class type, am I required to provide an appropriate `B operator=(B& poo)` for the original declaration to work?  Certainly I can do the following `int x, y, z` so why is the above generating a compiler error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer here is, don't declare multiple variables on one line. It's a pointless character saving that saves nothing on semantics whatsoever and merely leads to confusion. Don't use the `std::add_pointer_t` thing and don't just add more stars.

Comment: Since we can safely assume that `B` is just a placeholder name, not declaring multiple variables in *one declaration statement* is a clear violation of the DRY principle.

Comment: It's certainly not. Each of those variables is distinct and has their own distinct purpose. They should have their own distinct declaration.

Comment: What's the reasoning that a "distinct purpose" should lead to a distinct declaration? I find this claim entirely unbased.

Comment: Primarily because if they have distinct purposes, they have distinct reasons to change, which will lead to the need to change just one of the three. This just becomes more awkward if the declarations are combined. The fact that they *currently* have the same type is merely circumstantial.

Comment: @Puppy: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Comment: @Puppy Not necessarily. We're dissecting an example here, but consider `class BinaryTreeNode { BinaryTreeNode *left, *right; };` In this case, you *want* to express the symmetry between branches.

Answer (score 3):

This is an anachronism from C; the pointer asterisk (`*`) binds to the name, and not the type, yielding:

```
B* a;
B b;
B c;
```

A better, less error prone way to declare multiple raw pointers is this:

```
std::add_pointer_t<B> a, b, c;
```

> If you only have access to C++11, you need to use the more verbose `std::add_pointer<B>::type` instead.

---

In some codebases you might also find named typedefs for commonly used pointer types, like so:

```
typedef B* BPtr;
BPtr a, b, c;
```

Which yields what you'd expect. You can still use that, mixing and matching with `using` and `std::add_pointer`.

---

Alternatively, you can put a star in front of *every* name. That's why some people write this as:

```
B *a, *b, *c;
```

I'd personally discourage that. As mentioned before, it's not really readable and quite error-prone.

---

However, this assumes that your variables *should actually be of the same type*, which isn't coincidental. An example of such coincidence could be two numeric values happening to be `int`-s, but with no relationship between them. This is more of a design decision, though, and I assume that if you're asking about a single-type, multiple-name declaration, you understand what it entails.

Comment: Not familiar with `std::add_pointer<>::type - will look into it

Comment: @Mushy In practice, `std::add_pointer` is used in complex template situations, because it can be applied to things that `*` can't. However, typically your class members shouldn't be raw pointers in modern C++ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In the original declaration, `a` is of type `B*`, but `b` and `c` are of type `B`.

To make it work as a single declaration it should be

```
B* a, *b, *c;
```

IMHO I'd leave it as separate declarations if only to avoid the entire issue.

Comment: `B *a, *b, *c;` is a bit cleaner in this case in my opinion (note position of first space).